# Write down the matrix T with respect to $[T]_e^e$ and $[id]_b^e$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear transformation T, write down the matrix $[T]_e^e$ representing $T$ with respect to the standard basis $e$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the change of basis matrices  $[id]_b^e, [id]_e^b$.

I know that in order to find the matrix $[T]_e$ I have to solve for the coordinates $[T]=[e]$, but I am not clear about rest of this. What does this notation mean? Does it mean that I take the matrix $[T]_e= [e]$ and solve for the coordinates?